# How to get a JSON response without template in eZ Publish?

Tags: json, php-5.3, ezpublish

I intending to get a json response without rendering a view with eZ Publish.

So I trying to use a custom module to do that:

```
function jsonConvert(){

     $articles = eZFunctionHandler::execute(
              'content',
              'tree',
              array(
                  'parent_node_id' => '59'
              )
          );

    header("Content-Type: application/json");

    return json_encode($articles);
  }

  echo jsonConvert();
```

How can I compile this module without using a basic URL that rendering a view like domain.com/module/view/ in order to get a json response without any HTML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you :

1. use the builtin feature that allows you to use a different layout to render a content view. Create a new layout 'MYLAYOUT' within a layout.ini.append.php override (see https://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Configuration-files/layout.ini) and then call your view using /layout/set/MYLAYOUT/your/content/uri
2. specify the content type in the layout configuration to match your requirements (application/json as the content type)
3. create a pagelayout.tpl template used by your newly created layout which basically only contains {$module_result.content}
4. create a template operator to convert your contents into a 'readable' json and call it from the template rendering your content (probably a /node/view/full.tpl override)

alternative (but not that sexy) to #4 => call json_encode directly in your template by allowing the php function to be called in your templates (see https://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Configuration-files/template.ini/PHP/PHPOperatorList)

Comment: Thx a lot for your help foobar, it's working very well!

Comment: You're welcome ! Do you mind marking your question as resolved and the answer above as the good one ? :)

Answer (score 2):

```
echo json_encode( YOUR ARRAY );
eZExecution::cleanExit();
```

It's all what you need in your custom module/view php file to return json.

Answer (score 1):

To get a blank pagelayout in your module, and set a json content type, you can add this following lines in your module php file :

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$Result = array();
$Result['content'] = json_encode($articles);
$Result['pagelayout'] = false;
```